# Expression Tree printLevel() function

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am implementing a tree which is a Binary Expression Tree. The leaf nodes are numbers, non-leaf nodes are math operators. Succesfully implemented printInorder,PostOrder, PreOrder, evaluate. But stucked with the printLevel().

Here is my int main ()

```
int main()
{
    EXTree myTree;
    string tests[] = {"2.1*3.1+4.2", "(2.0+1.3)/1.4", "2.*(1.3+1.4)","1.2*(1.3+1.4/0.5)","1.2*(1.3+1.4/0.5)-4.4", "1.2*(1.3+1.4/0.5)- (9/3)"};
    for (int i=0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        myTree.build (tests[i]);
        myTree.printInorder();
        myTree.printPreorder();
        myTree.printPostorder();
        myTree.printLevel(); //Starting from level = 0
        cout << "Evaulating myTree = " << format(myTree.evaluate(),2) << endl;
        myTree.removeAll(); // removes all the nodes
    }
}
```

printLevel(); only prints the level of the tree given above and its initally 0.

and here is my printLevel function.

```
void EXTree:: printLevel()
{
    queue<Node*> levelq;

    levelq.push(root);
    cout << "Current Level is: ";
    while( levelq.size() > 0 )
    {
        Node *cur = levelq.front();
        cout << cur->Root << "  ";
        levelq.pop();
        if (cur->Left)  levelq.push(cur->Left);
        if (cur->Right) levelq.push(cur->Right);
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

But I really didnt understand how to implement the printLevel. Appreciate for any help to clarify it.

I just implemented the inOrder algorith to my printLevel and tried to change it but still didnt get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have no problem with recursion, this would work without `queue`:

```
void EXTree:: printLevel()
{
    int currentLevel = 0;
    if (root)
    {
        cout << "Current Level is: ";
        printLevelHelper(root,currentLevel);
    }
    else
        cout << "This BST is Empty\n";
}

// Declare a private method:
void EXTree:: printLevelHelper(Node* &n, int &currentLevel)
{
    cout << currentLevel << ' ';
    if (n->Left)
    {
        currentLevel++;
        printLevelHelper(n->Left,currentLevel);
        currentLevel--;
    }
    if (n->Right)
    {
        currentLevel++;
        printLevelHelper(n->Right,currentLevel);
        currentLevel--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. (Still trying to get the logic of that function :) )

Here is my output now;

    inOrder Traversal is :3.1 + 4.2 
    preOrder Traversal is :+ 3.1 4.2 
    postOrder Traversal is :3.1 4.2 + 
    Current Level is: 0
    Current Level is: 1
    Current Level is: 1
    Evaulating myTree = 7.3
    All nodes are removed succefully.
.
.
.

Comment: Another change, try it now, I had a bug, in the second (if) I also worte `printLevelHelper(n->Left,currentLevel);` while it should be (as now) `printLevelHelper(n->Right,currentLevel);`

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much. By the way, I also created another one that should work also. This is my code http://pastebin.com/gk6Sr0QR 

I am having one more problem which is , I cant insert more than 2 numbers in my string paranthesis one. for instance = string tests[] = {"(2.0+1.3+3.0)/1.4"}  //and it doesnt count 3.0

Comment: Tried it before, It works :) But how come that doesn't recognize the number when there are more than 2 in a paranthesis? Thats hard to find when theres a logic-mistake. (Thank you for your time, again.)

Comment: Welcome, haven't read your code, just a quick review, The problem I guess is that when the parser enters a `(`, he prepares to push 2 nodes: in `(2.0+1.3+3.0)` he finds 2.0 and creates a node for it, and so for 1.3, and then seeks the `)` directly. While in `(2.0+(1.3+3.0))` he finds 2.0 creates a node for it, for the second element he finds another `(` and so creates a new node and gets in the same process again with a recursive call (preparing to push 2 child nodes), then seeks `)` for the second call, and then for the first, End.

Comment: The parser is `buildRec` in your code as I see now, and at line 112 the recursive call happens.

Comment: Trying to fix it now, Thank you :)

Comment: I fixed it sir, Thanks again. I just realized I have one more mistake now for the first one which is 
`string tests[] = {"2.1*3.1+4.2"}` , I doesnt count 2.1 at start :/ Rest works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

When using Breadth First Search to print the nodes on one level immediately adjacent to each other, you'd just observe when the leftmost child of the leftmost node on the current level pops out of the queue: this must be the start of the next level. I could easily write the code but I'd guess it would incomprehensible for you and this homework is for you (I think you want to label your post appropriately as homework, BTW). Most of your implementation looks like a straight forward implementation. The only thing missing is detecting that the next level is reached.